# how to add css style and data-placement property="top" for tooltips using the title attr- Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add a tooltip on hover over an icon, I want to it a simple way, I'm adding the title attribute to get the tooltip

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="block">

</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div title="hovered text"data-placement="top" class="tooltiptext">
    
      <span class="tooltips"onmouseover="hover(this)">
   Hola hover</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4sp1ufgn/

however I havent found a way yet to :

1. style the tooltip using the title attribute
2. the data-placement property does not work on title attribute.

even when I have value as "top" for data-placement, it still renders below the text.
Any idea what would be the fix for the above 2 issues?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the w3schools example, which is written only in HTML and CSS.

[CSS Tooltip Example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)